# How do I move a tr tag back to the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have many tr in the visible area where it generates a scrollbar, tr each has its own id, how do I know if it is in the visible area of the scrollbar, and if not how do I place it in the visible area using Jquery ?

```
<tr align="center" id="100"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="101"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="102"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="103"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="104"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="105"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="106"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
<tr align="center" id="107"><td><a> info </a></td></tr>
```

Comment: Can you show your CSS, or jQuery (whichever it is that controls/sets the 'visible area' of the table)? And on what event do you want a given row to be made visible in that visible area? Do you want it to be scrolled, or simply moved from one place in the DOM to another place?

Comment: jQuery has a `:visible` selector.  `$('#id').is(':visible')`

Comment: I think you can use anchor links, but that would require a user clicking to go to that place in the table

Comment: @kyle, the last I checked the `:visible` selector only assesses whether an element is `display: none` or not, by assessing (I *think*) its dimensions, reference: "[Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)"; it doesn't assess whether it's visible to the user, as such.

Comment: @Kyle I think he means viewport visible.

Comment: The [`scrollTo`](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html) plugin for jQuery might be helpful for scrolling to a particular element ID.

Comment: ("place" == "scroll to") or ("place" == "re-order li elements")?

Comment: many more tr and can do more, if jquery has a :visible, how do I turn it on when tr is not in an area visible, with a if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/b5Bwx/

A quick and easy way:

```
$("div").on("scroll", function(){
   var y = $("#target").offset().top;
    if(y < this.offsetHeight && y > -$("target").height(){
        $("span").append("Visible");
    }
});
```

Or this: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Lxsmt/

Comment: Thank you, I is going well but I have a problem is that the table has a top and not as squarely, http://jsfiddle.net/b5Bwx/8/ Can you help me

Comment: @user987055 - Just a little note here: The `$("<div>")` is not an actual element that is used in the DOM. It is just a dummy node so that I can use the values returned by jQuery's `.animate()`. (So that I can animate `scrollTop`)

Answer (score 0):

To determine whether they are in the viewport or not, you will need to use a function to calculate that. Something like this would work (no jQuery required):

```
function isElementInViewport(el) {
    var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
        );
}
```

Then, you can scroll to them from a link like `<a href="#101">Go To Row 1</a>`.